# How to count in a range the number of cells having as a value multiple spaces (Excel, without VBA)

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to count in a specified range the number of cells whose value is only one or several spaces, without VBA.

My real use case is that I want to count, in a range, the number of empty cells, cells containing `0`, and cells containing only spaces (could be any number of spaces), for example  (x3).

This is what I tried:

1. **`NB.IF`**: Does not accept regular expression as a condition, we can only check for "any string" (`*`), and "any single character" (`?`).
2. **`SUBSTITUTE`** or **`TRIM`**: it replaces the spaces with nothing, so the cell is empty, but it works only with a single cell (and anyway the empty resulting cell does not match `ISBLANK`).
3. **`CNUM`**: Does not cast a space as a number.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will count all "0" (with find command) , all spaces (with trim)  and all empty (isblank) cells in a specific range:

```
=COUNT(IF(FIND("0",A:A,1),A:A,""))+COUNT(IF(A:A=SUBSTITUTE(A:A," ",""),A:A,"")+COUNT(IF(ISBLANK(A:A),A:A,""))
```

use array command (ctrl+shift+enter) when entering the formula.

Comment: It works fine with 0 or any number but doesn't with a string (tried `" "`, `"a"`...): the result is always 0 even if one or more cells contain one or more spaces...

Comment: Strange: I understand your formula but I don't understant why it does not work. `=COUNT(IF(T:T=TRIM(T:T),T:T,"")` counts only the empty cells in my case! A cell (let's say A1) with a string (`" "` included) or a number as a value will be excluded in the count, whereas when I calculate `=A1=TRIM(A1)`, it returns `TRUE`.

Comment: I checked this up and it works fine. please give me specific example.

Comment: I fill range C22:AG23 with a "x" in each cell, excepted one cell that contains a whitespace and another one that is empty. The result of `=COUNT(IF(C22:AG23=TRIM(C22:AG23),C22:AG23,""))` is 1 (due to the empty cell) and the result of `=COUNT(IF(C22:AG23<>TRIM(C22:AG23),C22:AG23,""))` is 0.

Comment: Ok I used `SUBSTITUTE(A:A," ","")` instead of TRIM and it works fine. Thank you very much for your help! (I didn't know anything about the "Array formula" with Ctrl+Shift+Enter).